# Possible to query As400 DB2 via VB.Net without a PRG?

Tags: vb.net, ibm-midrange, db2-400

After spending a few days researching and trying to figure this out solo, I could really use some help.

I'm trying to query the As400's database directly from .Net without the use of a As400 program file. I have very little support other than "go ahead and try" from the As400 administrators (I'm being told what I'm attempting hasn't been done here before).

I'd really like to use CWBX. The code below successfully connects, but I could really use a pointer in the right direction on how to build a query:

```
Dim As400 As New AS400System
Dim AsProgram As New cwbx.Program
Dim AsCommand As New cwbx.Command
Dim strQuery As String

As400.Define("AS400")
As400.UserID = ""
As400.Password = ""
As400.IPAddress = ""
As400.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd)

If As400.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) = 1 Then
    MsgBox("Valid Connection")
Else
    MsgBox("Invalid Connection")
    Exit Sub
End If

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Trying to figure out first if this syntax is correct, and if so... where/how to call it??
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM Library.File WHERE FILEFIELD='Criteria'"
' ---

AsProgram.LibraryName = ""
AsProgram.ProgramName = "" '?
AsProgram.system = As400

'Assuming this will end up being a program call?
'AsProgram.Call()

As400.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd)
```

I'm very open to any other methods/suggestions. I've looked for guides from IBM's site as well as MSDN and neither actually do direct querying without the use of an As400 program file. Is this even possible?

Comment: The search keywords that will help are ODBC and OLE DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple console app that will retrieve all the records from one table and display the row count.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim table As String = "YOUR TABLE"
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " & table
    Dim ip As String = "YOUR AS/400 IP GOES HERE"
    Dim user As String = "YOUR USER ID"
    Dim pass As String = "YOUR PASSWORD"
    Dim defaultLib As String = "YOUR LIBRARY"
    Dim connstring As String = "Provider=IBMDA400;" & _
                               "Data Source=" & ip & ";" & _
                               "Force Translate=0;" & _
                               "Default Collection=" & defaultLib & ";" & _
                               "User ID=" & user & ";" & _
                               "Password=" & pass
    cmd.Connection = New OleDbConnection(connstring)
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Load(dr)

    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count)
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close...")
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Note this is using the OLEDB driver.  There is a .NET data provider for IBM i.

Answer (score 1):

The remotecmd service is basically a Rexcd daemon.  Not sure why you're messing with that when you want to simple query a DB table.  The integrated DB in IBM i is accessible via ODBC, OLEDB, JBDC and most importantly for you a ADO.NET provider.

http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html

All of the above mentioned drivers are available in the IBM i Access software.  Note that while some of the IBM i Access features are chargeable, ex 5250 emulation, and you must have bought a license; the data access providers are not.

Included in the IBM i Access package is a collection of documentation known as the "Programmers Toolkit"

An example using the .NET data provider from that toolkit:

```
  Public Sub Example()
    Dim cn As iDB2Connection = New iDB2Connection("DataSource=mySystemi;")
      Dim da As New iDB2DataAdapter("select * from mylib.mytable", cn)
  End Sub
```

Lastly note that the (free) .NET provider doesn't support Microsoft's Entity Framework (EF).  If you need EF support, you'll have to pay for DB2 Connect

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2-connect-family